# Отправка изображение и pdf файла в одном сообщении

Tags: python, aiogram, aiogram-2.x

мне необходимо отправить в одном сообщении:

1. Изображение (верх сообщения)
2. Сам текст
3. PDF документ (низ сообщение)

В каком то боте видел, что можно отправить несколько файлов разного формата. Пробовал через `types.Media.Group()` - но он выдает ошибку что файлы разных форматов. Мне нужно не альбомом, а просто прикрепить к сообщению с фото еще и pdf. Возможно ли такое сделать?

Использую aiogram 2.7.5.

Comment: А верх сообщения, низ - это как?